# Select all differing ip addresses from one IP address

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm fairly new to Powershell but I've got a rather interesting problem. I have a logfile which contains different IP Addresses. The biggest portion of the logfile is localhost generated content.

I want to filter all those entries which are NOT from the certain localhost ip.

How would I do that with REGEXs or is there a more elegant solution?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to select lines with a particular ip try:

```
 get-content c:\mylogfile.log | select-string -pattern '192.168.1.100'
```

to select lines without a particular ip try:

```
 get-content c:\mylogfile.log | ? { $_ -notmatch '192.168.1.100' }
```

to select lines without a particalr ip but with at least an ip try:

```
 get-content c:\mylogfile.log | ? { $_ -notmatch '192.168.1.100' } |
? { $_ -match '\b(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\b' }
```

Comment: As far as my understanding goes I would select every line which contains the IP address 192.168.1.100? But I want to select EVERY line which does not contain that certain ip address.

Comment: The second code is displaying the lines without the IP - but many lines don't contain an IP at all.

get-content .\extracted_ip_addresses.txt | select-string -pattern '(?!(127\.0\.0\.1))(\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b)' is doing what I want :).